# asp.net client side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, client

I need to write a validation code based on the selection made from 2 `drop downs` in the `modal popup` in ASP.net code.
How do I get the selected value of these controls on button (inside the popup) click from javascript? 
Can someone suggest me a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
var stateId=$('<%= stateList.ClientID%>').val();
alert(stateId);
```

Or you can take benefit of

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

It will stop the id to change at runtime.

Details
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature

### Edit 1

```
function validateTime() 
{ 
     var fh = ('<%= cboFromTimeHours.SelectedValue%>'); 
     var fm = ('<%= cboFromTimeMins.SelectedValue%>'); 
     alert(fh);
     alert(fm);
     var ft = (parseInt(fh) * 60) + parseInt(fm); alert(ft); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Shekhar, I am getting the value in alert box as NaN.

Comment: are your trying to cast the values into int or float?

Comment: Hi Shekhar, I am getting the value now. I used var fh = ('<%= cboFromTimeHours.SelectedValue%>'); I have a small problem. I need to get a result in alert like ((fromhour * 60) + fromminutes.) How do I do this?

Comment: what is fromhour and fromminutes?

Comment: It is just value from the dropdowns. I need to get a result like the one specified. (value of fromhour * 60) + (value of from minutes)

Comment: Adding code for your reference ..








`function validateTime() {
            var fh = ('<%= cboFromTimeHours.SelectedValue%>');
            var fm = ('<%= cboFromTimeMins.SelectedValue%>');
            var ft = (fh * 60) + fm;
            alert(ft);
        }`

Comment: Shekhar, awesome buddy. You saved my day :) Millions of thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript, you can use `getElementById` method

```
var stateId=document.getElementById('stateList').value;
alert(stateId);
```

If you have jQuery library available, you can get the selected value like this

```
var stateId=$('#stateList').val();
alert(stateId);
```

Assuming `stateList` is the ID of your SELECT element.

Comment: Hi Shyju, I am getting an error like "value is undefined". I am using VS 2012.